# Only show row with highest ID? (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I would like a one line row on my site where that reads: Latest registered person: x

And the person x is the person with highest ID (which is auto_increment)..

How would that code look like?

```
SELECT * 
FROM characters 
LIMIT 1 
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close:

```
SELECT *
FROM characters
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The syntax requires the `ORDER BY` to come before `LIMIT`, and you should have added a `DESC` to the `ORDER BY`, to get the last, not the furst user.

Comment: May I also ask how I would show like: "number of registered members" by showing the highest amount ID?

Comment: That's not recommended, because it will be bigger than the actual number if you delete some records. Instead, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM characters`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` should do it, to get the highest `id` first.

Comment: LIMIT must come after ORDER BY

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1`